# EF AsNoTracking Causes error. Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Today I decided to upgrade an old web project of mine from Asp.net core 1.1 to 2.1 and all was going quite smoothly until I attempted to retrieve a list of LocalEvent's from the DB. I was using .AsNotracking as I didn't need to make any changes to the objects beyond sorting / filtering.

This is the error:

> Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for assignment to
>   type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'

This is the code I am having issues with:

```
    var today = DateTime.Now;

    var events = await _context.LocalEvent.Where
    (x => x.ReoccurUntil > today || x.EventEnd > today).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

This is the LocalEvent model:

```
public class LocalEvent
{
    [NotMapped]
    private DateTime? dateCreated;

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Event Location")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Added By")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Contact")]
    public string EventContact { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event Name")]
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Details")]
    public string EventInfo { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Cost")]
    public Decimal? EventCost { get; set; }

    //DateStuff
    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated
    {
        get { return dateCreated ?? DateTime.Now; }
        set { dateCreated = value; }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Event Start")]
    public DateTime EventStart { get; set; }


    [DateGreaterThan("EventStart")]
    [Display(Name = "Event End")]
    public DateTime EventEnd { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReoccurUntil { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Reoccurrence Type")]
    public TypeOfOccurrence OccurrenceType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Which Occurence of Weekday")]
    public Nth NthReOccurence { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Weekday for Reoccurence")]
    public DayOfWeek ReoccurrenceDay { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Occurrence Rate")]
    public OccurrenceRate Occurrence { get; set; }
    public bool DoesReoccur { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Image { get; set; }

    public string ImageDeletePath { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}
```

For now I simply removed the AsNoTracking to get things working again.  Am I doing something wrong?

The error is really weird because it mentions dates and so took a while to trace back to the AsNoTracking, I removed anything to do with dates, initially just removing nullable dates, then I realised a similar call for the admin list (a complete tracked list) worked with the only difference being AsNoTracking, and that's when (after testing) I decided to ask on here.

I was of the mind that if I have no intention of modifying, deleting etc I should avoid tracking to improve performance!?

Hopefully someone can shed a bit of light on the issue! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by EF Core bug introduced in v2.1.

Reported and tracked by [#12215: Exception when loading entity containing a primitive property with matching System.Nullable backing field](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12215).

No workaround provided, fix scheduled for v2.2.

What I can suggest is to force EF using the property rather than the backing field:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<LocalEvent>()
        .Property(e => e.DateCreated)
        .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Property);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I thought I was going mad! Thanks 

Comment: Question for you both -- I encountered the same error with the same use case (nullable DateTime used for a db record creation date). The bug report Ivan linked questions the practice: "It's surprising that this worked in 2.0. Having a property that returns a different value than it was set to will often result in issues. For example, using this pattern, how do you ensure that -1 is not saved to the database?" Is there something wrong with the way we are using this nullable DateTime? Is there any drawback to forcing EF to use the property as in Ivan's answer?

Comment: PS looks like they changed the milepost to v3.0.0 so it could be awhile before this gets fixed.

Comment: @Jim Eventually with EF Core change tracking. Since the property getter in this particular case returns different value on each call (when the field is `null`). If the "default" value is constant/fixed, then I see no problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry, can you elaborate on that? So the property getter will return a unique value (DateTime.now) when field is null, but that should only happen when it is a new record and we are stamping it with a creation date right? In this case there is no real default value, the record starts life with a null value there but can't be saved without the current date/time being applied. Is there a better way to do this? By EF Core change tracking do you mean they will be building this functionality in to EF so we don't need to hand code it? Thank you for the reply!!

Comment: @Jim I mean expression `dateCreated ?? DateTime.Now` will continue returning different value even after EF Core saves the record in the database. Or in other words, if the record is not loaded from the database, the property will show value different from what is/will be stored in the database. Of course only for new object. Still can be confusing / mess up some EFC or your own logic. But actually this is entity design issue and has nothing to do with aforementioned bug.